# Match 2 vectors of expressions in R

Tags: r

Sample data

```
vector1 <- data.frame(name1=c("amsterdam, i.o.","jiřom e.g.", "higgins dec e.o.")) 
vector2 <- data.frame(name2=c("hello no e.y.","jiřom e.g.","oxford road w.o.o"),num=c(2,3,4))
```

I tried this approach, but it fails on some expressions. What would be the bullet proof solution? Would regex solution solve it?

```
 vector1$vec1 <- vector2$num[match(vector1$name1,vector2$name2)]
```

The above works on this occasion and the bellow result is the desired outcome.

```
              name1  vec1
 1  amsterdam, i.o.   NA
 2       jiřom e.g.    3
 3 higgins dec e.o.   NA
```

Comment: (1) those are data frames, not vectors. (2) they were coerced to factors when put in a data frame.  Are they vectors or data frames?  I would suggest using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` if they're not factor levels.

Comment: You are absolutely right!Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
vector1 <- merge(vector1, vector2, by.x = "name1", by.y = "name2", all.x = T)
```

Comment: You are right!I didn't think about approaching it this way.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the operator `%in%` is what you are looking for:

```
vector2$num[vector2$name2 %in% vector1$name1]
```

Does this help?

**edit**

`%in%` and `match` are not exactly similar. From the help page:

> match returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its
>   first argument in its second.
>
> %in% is a more intuitive interface as a binary operator, which returns
>   a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for its left
>   operand.

So, `match` will not return all the matches, but only the first one, whereas `%in%` will work for all matches.

**edit 2**

Here is a simple illustration of the difference between `match` and `%in%`, using a slightly modified example which should return `3` and `5`:

```
> vector1 <- data.frame(name1=c("amsterdam, i.o.","jiřom e.g.", "higgins dec e.o.")) 
> vector2 <- data.frame(name2=c("hello no e.y.","jiřom e.g.","jiřom e.g.","oxford road w.o.o"),num=c(2,3,5,4))
> vector2$num[vector2$name2 %in% vector1$name1]
[1] 3 5
> vector2$num[match(vector1$name1,vector2$name2)]
[1] NA  3 NA
```

Comment: I have tried this approach already, it leaves out some characters.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of a failed application?

Comment: You should give an example where it leaves something out. Also you're matching strings, right?

Comment: @Max: The problem could be with `match` not matching multiple occurrences (see the edited answer). At least it is a difference between our two approaches. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I'm sorry I can not reproduce it. I would have to find first the string where it fails...and it fails on more then 1 instance anyway..

Comment: Without a reproducible example of your problem it is impossible for others to help :)

Comment: @Jealie: You are explaining all around what I already know..your edit2 is unnecessary, but thanks

Comment: You should probably convert to `character` as the original data are `factor`.